# ffmpeg cut audio to video length if its longer in video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video in which the video is 7 sec and audio is 10 sec. i happened to get like this when i was triming from a video. using `-ss and -t`

The video pauses and and audio continues when i play in mpv.

how to trim the audio to video length within the video.

presently the only option i am left is to remove the audio completely, so that the video plays for 5 sec and quits.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset:v slow -b:v 830k -movflags +faststart -an out.mp4` (with video of 5 sec and no audio)

Comment: You should show the complete console output from your command. The actual issue may be revealed in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a video in which the video is 7 sec and audio is 10 sec. i happened to get like this when i was trimming from a video. using `-ss` and `-t`

It often happens when using the `-ss` and `-t` together with `-c copy` or `-codec copy`.

Don't copy, and use another codecs or simply don't specify `-c` , `-codec` options. and this won't happen.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `-shortest` output option.

From the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> `-shortest` *(output option)*
>   Finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends.

Comment: I get a small difference (in order of milliseconds) when I use -shortest option, is there a way I can avoid this? as I will concatenate a large number of videos and am afraid that audio and video will be out of sync, thanks!